# Multiplying an array with a matrix R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

When I have an array with the dimension (i,j,k) and a matrix with the dimension (j,q). How could I multiply each (,,k) with that matrix. An example makes more sense.

```
A <- array(c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20), rep(3,20)),dim = c(10,2,3))
B <- matrix(c(1:10), nrow = 2)
# multiply each A[,,i]%*%B

C <- array(NA, dim=c(nrow(A), ncol(B), 3))
C[] <- apply(A, 3, function(x) x%*%B)
```

I could get the results in this way, but I am looking for a more efficient way, for example with the ATensor package. I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Your solution should be pretty efficient. You benchmarked it?

Comment: For runtime efficiency parallelisation could be better. The coding efficiency is just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, okay maybe another question when could I use tensor calculations. I don't understand mainly when the Atensor package is useful in calculations with multidimensional arrays.